# Bad Request returned when calling Yammer Oauth api for Impersonation

Tags: api, yammer

I'm working on building a powershell script to update user's profiles in Yammer.  I need to be able to update users' subscriptions (followers) in their yammer profile and in order to do that, I need to get an auth token for that user (impersonation).  According to Yammer's api documentation (https://developer.yammer.com/docs/impersonation), I need to be a verified admin (I am).  I've registered my app with Yammer, I have a bearer token for my app which I'm passing in the auth header, and I'm passing in the consumer key and user_id for whom I want to impersonate in the api request query string.  The api is responding with a 400 - Bad Request.  The error message states that the request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax.  I'm testing this using Postman.  I am sending a GET request to the API as shown below.  Obviously, I have actual values for the userId and consumerKey values.  Does anything appear incorrect with this query and/or does anyone have any experience with this api that could possibly share some insight?

[https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/oauth/tokens.json?user_id=*userId*&consumer_key=*consumerKey*](https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/oauth/tokens.json?user_id=_userId_&consumer_key=_consumerKey_)